# Massive Frame Rate after rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm rendering using 720p, with 2000 FPS. After rendering, I'm getting a huge file with 244 frames/second. The source files are only 29.97 frames/second so why is the render going up almost 10 times???

[image: Frame Rate]
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you rendering? A 3D scene? Compositor? Video Sequence editor? You say your source files have 29.97 frames per second and you are rendering with 2000 (?) frames per second, why such an unusually high value, more than 60 times the original value? What were you expecting would happen to file size with such high frame rate?

Comment: Do you mean 2000 *frames* (not frames per second).

Comment: Rendering video thru the NLE

Answer (score 2):

Check your render settings. To get 29.97 fps you should have a framerate of 30 with a framerate base of 1.001. If you change the base to 0.123 then you will get 243.9 fps

[image: render settings]

Comment: I am rendering videos thru the NLE.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my Dimension and Encoding menus

Comment: My video length is 2:15:58 but when I render say, 10 mins of video, everything comes out just fine. It's only after I render the full length that I get the huge rates

Comment: Interesting, current releases have a max frame count of 300,000 (for 2.77 it has been increased to 500,000),  I wonder if exporting large frame counts to video has a bug. Can you find a frame count where this starts happening? If you export using other codecs does the same thing happen? I would [report this](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug) as a bug and see if the developers can find a cause for bad frame rates with longer videos.

Comment: How can I look for that? Render it out 10 mins at a time?

Comment: I would just pick some frame lengths to narrow it down. We expect 244,000 fails does 200,000 fail? does 150,000 fail? depending on the time to export each step you could use closer frame lengths to get as close as you can. Of course we expect the error to happen close to the 244,000 frames used not with anything over 50,000

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to blender and uploaded some of the files. https://developer.blender.org/T47844

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.blender.org/T47844

After more than a week talking to some guys, it appears the problem is not the actual video itself, rather the way Windows is reporting the status.